# Input type text and onKeyDown not working under IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, dhtml

I am writing a WWW application, it has to run under IE. I have the problem with the code that runs under Firefox, but I can't get it running under IE.

// JS code

```
function test()
{
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13)
        window.location.assign("myPage.php");
}
```

I've tried some similar ways around `window.location` and `location.href`, also `document.location`. I've read that IE has problems with that, so I ask for a solution.

The goal is, that page reloads after typing in some text into `<input type='text' name='item_code' onKeyDown='test()'>` and click <kbd>enter</kbd>. So the result is similar to pressing submit type button below the text input.

Within IE it reloads the same page and nothing happens. In Firefox it works correctly.

**UPDATE 1:**

Tried solution given by bobince.

```
<input type='text' name='item_code'>

<script type='text/javascript' >
 
document.getElementsByName('item_code')[0].onkeydown = function(event)
{
    if (event == undefined) { event = window.event; }
    if (event.keyCode == 13) { window.location = 'myPage.php'; }
        
    alert('1');
}
    
</script>";
```

The problem is, that if there is `alert('1');` line, page shows alert and redirects, if there isn't `alert('1');` line, page just reloads to itself. I don't know what is the problem here?

**UPDATE 2:**

I'am pasting what finally works for me.

```
<form action='mainPage.php' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='item_code'>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript' >
    document.getElementsByName('item_code')[0].onkeydown= function(event)
    {
        if (event == undefined)
        {    
            event = window.event;
        }

        if (event.keyCode == 13)
        {
            var js_item_code = document.getElementsByName('item_code')[0].value;
            window.location = 'myPage.php?item_code='+js_item_code;
            return false;
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: How about `window.location.href = "myPage.php";`

Comment: `window.location.href` doesn't have an `assign` method (`window.location` does).  However, I don't think this is your problem because the same is true (and will throw an error) in Firefox.  You also have some other typos in your code (which I fixed, but you edited them back in :-))

Comment: oh, didn't know, pls edit them again if you can, appreciate your input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's strange, because your use of `window.event` should ensure your function **only** ever works in IE. That's certainly what happens for me when I try your code. I suspect there is more you're not showing us.

The usual way to handle events in a cross-browser way with inline event handler attributes would be:

```
<input type="text" name="item_code" onkeydown="test(event)">

function test(event) {
    if (event.keyCode===13)
        window.location.href= 'myPage.php';
}
```

This works because `event` in the attribute refers to the global `window.event` in IE, where in every other browser it refers to a local argument named `event` passed in to the event handler attribute function.

However, it is generally considered better to avoid event handler attributes and assign handlers from JavaScript itself. In this case you need a check to see which to use:

```
<input type="text" name="item_code">

// in a script block after the input, or in document-ready code
//
document.getElementsByName('item_code')[0].onkeydown= function(event) {
    if (event===undefined) event= window.event; // fix IE
    if (event.keyCode===13)
        window.location.href= 'myPage.php';
};
```

In general I would only try to trap Enter keypresses to reproduce/alter default form submission behaviour as a last resort; better if you can to let the form submit to the place you want it to go.

Comment: Ok. Tried your solution and it seems to work. Have one subtle problem though. It only works when `alert('sth');` is after 2nd if block: the page show an alert and redirects. If i remove this alert line, page reloads to itself..

Comment: If you are in an actual `<form>` element then you will need to add `return false` to the event handler, otherwise the form will continue to submit as normal for pressing the Enter button, and end up at the form's `action` attribute (defaulting to the current URL if omitted, though omitting it is invalid). If you have a form and you want to trap submission on it (via Enter or any other means) it is far better to use the `onsubmit` event rather than worry about recreating browser-specific key handling behaviour.

Comment: Of course it's better still to have the form simply work without any JavaScript hacking. If that's not possible for some reason, it's better to omit the `<form>` and just include bare `<input>` elements so there is no unwanted submission.

Comment: I am more experienced with compiled languages. I will appreciate more descriptive answer. Now i understand why it's working such way. Don't know a) which one is an event handler (to add return false)? b) where should i use onsubmit event?

Comment: `onsubmit` is on `<form>`. You can `return false` from a submit handler to stop the form being submitted. [You can also `return false` on a submit button's `onclick` handler to stop the click causing the form to be submitted. You can also `return false` on an input's `onkeypress` handler to stop the Enter keypress causing the form to submit. You can also `return false` on an input's `onkeydown` handler to stop the keydown causing a `keypress`, which in turn also stops the form being submitted! But blocking `onsubmit` is the most reliable as it catches all cases.]

Comment: `window.event` also works in recent (and probably also older) versions of Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your help. I've pasted what finally works for me in main post.

Answer (score 0):

try this. it has worked for me earlier.

```
 <input type="text" onKeyPress="KeyCheck"/>

 function KeyCheck(e) {
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    if (KeyID == 13 ) {
       alert('key pressed!!);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This won't work. `onKeyPress` is now a function that makes a reference to the `KeyCheck` function and then does nothing with it. `KeyCheck` will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

It should work in general. Two potential problems you may have run into:

1. IE is known to do weird things when using relative links in location.href. Have you tried putting something like http://stackoverflow.com in there?
2. Security settings in IE may prevent the right thing from happening if i.e. you are testing on a local file rather than a web server.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery fix

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    var event = jQuery.event.fix(e || window.event);
    var keycode = event.which;
    var isControl = event.ctrlKey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make it work without using the `<form>` tag on your html code.

This is the simplest solution I found that works with IE, Chrome and Firefox at least:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input#q").on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      document.location.assign("page.aspx?q=" + $("#q").val());
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input name="q" type="text" />
```