# JavaScript form submit to database using Ajax and Laravel route

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, laravel

I'm making a quiz website using `Laravel, Javascript and Ajax` and I made an add form function with JavaScript like this:

[image]

But I want to send the form data (to create a new quiz question) into my Laravel `QuizController` route using Ajax, after the focus on the form is lost or after an enter..
But I can't figure out how to do it.

---

*My JavaScript/Ajax:*

```
var limit = 1;
var count = 0;
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
var container = document.getElementById('container');


function createQuestion() {

if(count < limit) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = 'text';
    input.id = '';
    input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control')
    container.appendChild(input);
    count++;
}
else {
    alert ('Enter this question first before you can add another question!');
}
}


function storeQuestion() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        //
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

---

*My Laravel.blade:*

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>

    {!! Form::button('Add Quiz', array('onclick' => 'createQuiz()', 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'id' => 'myButton', 'value' => 'Add question')) !!}
```

---

*My QuestionController:*

```
public function store(Quiz $quiz)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $input['quiz_id'] = $quiz->id;
    Question::create($input);

    return Redirect::route('quizzes.show', $quiz->slug)->with('message', 'Question created.');
}
```

I hope someone can help me because I'm pretty stuck up with this problem for some time..

Answer (score 0):

To use AJAX instead of standard HTTP POST you should catch enter and blur events.

How to catch enter is explained in first answer to [input type text and onKeyDown not working under IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577868/input-type-text-and-onkeydown-not-working-under-ie) but in test for enter you should run storeQuestion

to add blur add :

```
<input type="text" name="item_code" onkeydown="test(event)" onblur="storeQuestion()">
```

Your store function should not return a Redirect::route but some status code or JSON string. If you use laravel 4 http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.html that would just say "OK" or true or error

You should modify storeQuestion to add the new answer/edit/delete buttons to the list also. ( // )

A simpler way would be to not use AJAX but just submit the form with javascript after focus is lost by attaching an onblur event handler to the textbox.

Comment: It is an assignment for school and we need to use AJAX to send our form into the database

Comment: and xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true); is probably not good . you should call the store route/function from the controller

Answer (score 0):

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

queryString = "access_token=" + access_token + "&data=" + data;

req3.open('GET', '/path/of/laravel/route?' + queryString, true);

req3.send(queryString)